# Error displayed after Default.srprofile is modified

Tags: specflow

I have modified .srprofile to configure my own report template.

But when executed thrown with below error message and html file is not generated -

System.InvalidOperationException: render template resource not found
   at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.Reporting.ReportTemplateLoader.LoadTemplate(Report report)....

Changes done to .srprofile:

```
  <Report copyAlsoToBaseFolder="true">
<Template name="ReportTemplate.cshtml" outputName="AutomationReport.html" />
 </Report>"
```

Did i do anything wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpecFlow+Runner is searching for the ReportTemplate.cshtml in the output directory (normally bin\debug). If you add the file to the project, in default it is not copied to the output directory.

Change "copy to output" in the properties of the file to "always"

Comment: Hi @Andreas - Thank You for the reply. Below are the steps whichi have done, please let me know if there is any wrongly done -

1) Copied ReportTemplate.cshtml (which is in packages folder) and pasted into the project. And marked Copy to Output as "always" as you suggested. When i build the project it is getting copied into "debug" folder.
2) When I executed my scenario - got below error -

Comment: Continuation:
RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateParsingException: (112:5) - Unexpected "if" keyword after "@" character.  Once inside code, you do not need to prefix constructs like "if" with "@".
   at RazorEngine.Compilation.CSharp.CSharpRazorCodeGenerator.VisitError(RazorError err)
   at System.Web.Razor.Parser.ParserVisitorExtensions.Visit(ParserVisitor self, ParserResults result)

Comment: Continuation: As i can see there are errors in cshtml file, i have removed all "@" before if's and executed again. This time my report got generated in the "debug" folder. In the output window i can see report is generated, when i clicked on html file, blank page is displayed.

Comment: Also i cannot copy paste whole error. Could you please tell me why i got blank page. ??

Comment: Some part of that big error  - More details about the error:
 - error: (767, 71) The name 'HttpEncode' does not exist in the current context
  - error: (1276, 103) The name 'HttpEncode' does not exist in the current context
  - error: (1443, 29) The name 'HttpEncode' does not exist in the current context
  - error: (1477, 47) The name 'HttpEncode' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Looks like you have a compilation error in your Report template. We are using Razor for it.

Comment: How to remove those compilation error? Any suggestions?

Comment: Hey @Andreas - I looked into one of your specflow examples project which was mentioned in your stackoverflow profile and copied the cshtml code with yours. Now i am able to generate the report. Thank You.

- Now i have another problem - when i am embedding a screenshot i was printed like this in the report - SCREENSHOT[ file:///C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2015_Backup\Projects\MyProject.Specs\TestResults\tmp6AF1.jpg ]SCREENSHOT

Any help?

Comment: Please send an email to support@specflow.org or open an issue at https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues. It is easier to troubleshoot your problem.